# NSUserDefault Custom object error - "array cannot be bridged from Objective-C"

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

On the line that contains `return goal //**//` my program crashes and gives me the error: "fatal: array cannot be bridged from Objective-C". Could anyone know what this is from?

```
func saveGoals (goals : [Goal]) {
    var updatedGoals = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(goals)
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(updatedGoals, forKey: "Goals")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}

func loadCustomObjectWithKey() -> [Goal?] {
    if let encodedObject : NSData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Goals") as? NSData {
        var encodedObject : NSData? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Goals") as? NSData
        var goal : [Goal] = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(encodedObject!) as [Goal]
        return goal //**//
    } else {
        return [Goal]()
    }
}
class GoalsViewController: MainPageContentViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
@IBOutlet var tableView: GoalsTableView!
var goalsArray : Array<Goal> = [] //

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self

        if var storedGoals: [Goal] = loadCustomObjectWithKey() as? [Goal] {
            goalsArray = storedGoals
        }

        //retrieve data.

        if var storedGoalList: [Goal] = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("GoalList") as? [Goal]{
            goalsArray = storedGoalList;
        }

        var goal = Goal(title: "Walk the Dog")
        goalsArray.append(goal)
        saveGoals(goalsArray)

        self.tableView?.reloadData()

        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

    }
}
```

Comment: This is now a completely different question from the original.  My best guess is Goal doesnt properly implement NSCoding.

Comment: Alrighty, I will create a new thread and restore this one to earlier edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to return a [Goal] as [Goal?]. Since the array content types don't match (and can't match) you get a runtime exception. Changed the return type to [Goal], particularly since you always return something anyway.

Comment: Thank you, now I receive a separate error however. Look above.